# C - Switch with multiple case numbers

Tags: c, switch-statement, case

So my professor asked us to create a switch statement. We are allowed to use **only the "SWITCH"** statement to do the program. He wants us to input a number and then display it if it is on the number range and what briefcase number will be taken as shown below. Now... I know that for this type of program it is easier to use the **IF statement**. Doing Case 1: Case 2: Case 3...Case 30 will work but will take too much time due to the number range.

```
#include <stdio.h>
main()
{
      int x;
      char ch1;
      printf("Enter a number: ");
      scanf("%d",&x);
      switch(x)
      {
                 case 1://for the first case #1-30
                 case 30:
                      printf("The number you entered is >= 1 and <= 30");
                      printf("\nTake Briefcase Number 1");
                      break;         
                 case 31://for the second case #31-59
                 case 59:
                      printf("The number you entered is >= 31 and <= 59");
                      printf("\nTake Briefcase Number 2");
                      break;                 
                 case 60://for the third case #60-89
                 case 89:
                      printf("The number you entered is >= 60 and <= 89");
                      printf("\nTake Briefcase Number 3");
                      break;                 
                 case 90://for the fourth case #90-100
                 case 100:
                      printf("The number you entered is >= 90 and <= 100");
                      printf("\nTake Briefcase Number 4");
                      break;      
                 default:
                     printf("Not in the number range");
                     break;

                 }
      getch();
      }
```

My professor told us that there is a shorter way on how to do this but won't tell us how. The only way I can think of shortening it is by using IF but we are not allowed to. Any Ideas on how I can make this work out?

Comment: Just to check, are you sure the first case goes from 1 to 30? and not 1 to 29?

Comment: Are you thinking `case 1: case 30:` will match any number in the range? It won't.

Comment: Your first pair of `case` labels only find 2 values: 1 and 30; they ignore 2..29. Ditto for the next 'range', etc.  Using switch only, you are in for a world of pain.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

With GCC and Clang, you can use case ranges, like this:

```
switch (x){

case 1 ... 30:
    printf ("The number you entered is >= 1 and <= 30\n");
    break;
}
```

The only cross-compiler solution is to use case statements like this:

```
switch (x){

case 1:
case 2:
case 3:
case 4:
case 5:
case 6:
    printf ("The number you entered is >= 1 and <= 6\n");
    break;
}
```

**Edit:** Using something to the effect of `switch (x / 10)` is another good way of doing this. It may be simpler to use GCC case ranges when the ranges aren't differences of `10`, but on the other hand your professor might not take a GCC extension as an answer.

Comment: Bonus question: is it necessary to put each `case` on a distinct line? This question is due to the `goto-label`-alike behaviour of the `switch case`

Comment: I've got a question about ur first example, is there a way to specify 2 completely different variables like a char and int for one case? -> is this a good way to do it case addr, 0xFF:

Comment: @OskarGarczyński no, not that I know of. `0xFF` as a signed char type is `-0x01`, maybe that's an option. If not, you'd be better of casting the variable in the switch expression.

Answer (score 12):

If the ranges are consistent, then you can throw away some of the data:

```
switch (x / 10 ) {
   case 0:
   case 1:
   case 2:  // x is 0 - 29
     break ;

   // etc ...
}
```

Otherwise you'll have to do a little bit of hackery around the edges.

Comment: +1: More or less — `(x - 1)/10` would give `[012]` for 1..30; repeat. The trouble will be -8..0 (also giving 0).

Answer (score 5):

```
   Try this ...

#include <stdio.h>
main() {
      int x;
      char ch1;
      printf("Enter a number: ");
      scanf("%d",&x);
      int y=ceil(x/30.0);
      switch(y) {
                 
                 case 1:
                      printf("The number you entered is >= 1 and <= 30");
                      printf("\nTake Briefcase Number 1");
                      break;         
                 
                 case 2:
                      printf("The number you entered is >= 31 and <= 60");
                      printf("\nTake Briefcase Number 2");
                      break;                 
                
                 case 3:
                      printf("The number you entered is >= 61 and <= 90");
                      printf("\nTake Briefcase Number 3");
                      break;                 
                 
                 case 4:
                      printf("The number you entered is >= 91 and <= 100");
                      printf("\nTake Briefcase Number 4");
                      break;      
                 default:
                     printf("Not in the number range");
                     break;

                 }
      getch();
      }
```

Comment: Your current use of `ceil()` is slightly incorrect. You attempt it on the integer division of `x` by `30`, which is already integer because integer division is floored. Perhaps did you mean `ceil(x/30.0)`?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't do that myself because the edit is less than 6 characters. If you could do that yourself, I'd gladly delete both these comments.