# multiple label value in C switch case

Tags: c, switch-statement

Following is the excerpt from  Dennis M Ritchie's book, ANSI C:

> Each case is labeled by one or more integer-valued constants or constant expressions.

I could not come up with an example of a switch case where we have **case with more than one label**.

Any example illustrating the above property will be helpful.

Comment: I don't think so, I have read that answer but it is not using more than one labels for a single case.

Comment: I think he is referring to a single case with more than 1 label. Please correct me if I m wrong.

Comment: @ashunigon: that example uses two case labels on each case (except for the default)

Comment: Yes, I think now I comprehend.

Comment: Should I delete this question or leave it.

Comment: @achal: [That](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20208628/c-switch-with-multiple-case-numbers) is not a duplicate. It has some misguided attempt to use case labels to specify ranges, and the top answer uses a language extension. I do not like any of the top search results for “[C] multiple case” as a clear question and answer for this. Perhaps we should answer it simply and directly and use this question for it.

Comment: @EricPostpischil it will be great if someone could answer this question more directly...things are not crystal clear, as even google does not have a perfect answer for this and as a result I had to ask .

Comment: @ChrisDodd: The question you markes this as a duplicate of does not correctly use two labels on each case. It attempts to use two labels as a range, and the top answer recommends a language extension. It is not a good Q&A to present normal use of multiple labels in C.

Comment: There are many equally valid examples with no way to choose a single correct one among them, therefore the question is too broad as defined by the guidelines.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's an example I found in a program which checks options:

```
switch (optionChar) {
    case 'a': case 'A':
    case 'f': case 'F':
    case 'q': case 'Q':
    case 'z': case 'Z': optionsOk = TRUE;  break;
    default:            optionsOk = FALSE; break;
}
```

It's probably not how I would have written the code<sup>(a)</sup> but it's certainly valid. It's often used when the use of `case` results in shorter code than a long seties of `||` conjunctions for conditions that need substantially similar actions:

```
if (optionChar == 'a' || optionChar == 'A' || ...
```

---

And, in fact, K&R itself has an example, *right after the quote you mention.* It's in the code for counting different character classes:

```
while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
    switch (c) {
    case '0': case '1': case '2': case '3': case '4':
    case '5': case '6': case '7': case '8': case '9':
        ndigit[c-'0']++;
        break;
    case ' ': case '\n': case '\t':
        nwhite++;
        break;
    default:
        nother++;
        break;
    }
}
```

---

<sup>(a)</sup> I probably would have done something along the lines of:

```
optionsOk = (strchr("aAfFqQzZX", optionChar) != NULL);
```

Comment: Is fall through what is meant by a case having more than one label?

Comment: @Mercer, I would think so, this is K&R after all - there weren't any fancy features beyond fallthrough :-)

Answer (score 1):

The `gcc` compiler has an extension for multiple values in a single `case` clause, such as:

```
case 1 ... 8:
```

However, it does not conform to the C standard.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is correct for C++ too. Stroustup's book Programming Principles says the same.

> You can use several case labels for a single case. Often you want the same action for a set of values in a switch. It would be tedious to repeat the action so you can label a single
>   action by a set of case labels. For example:

He has given the following example:

```
    int main() // you can label a statement with several case labels
    {
    cout << "Please enter a digit\n";
    char a;
    cin >> a;
    switch (a) {
        case '0': case '2': case '4': case '6': case '8':
        cout << "is even\n";
        break;
    case '1': case '3': case '5': case '7': case '9':
        cout << "is odd\n";
        break;
    default:
        cout << "is not a digit\n";
        break;
        }
    }
```