# what is the difference between using the same value for two case labels and using several case labels for a single case?

Tags: c++, switch-statement, label, case

I was reading from *Bjarne's Programming and Principles using C++*.

I ran into the following details about **switch**:

> You can use several case labels for a single case.
>
> You cannot use the same value for two case labels.

I think I clearly understand the 2. one. It should mean that:

```cpp
switch (a) {

  case 'c':{//some code} 

  case 'c':{//some (different) code} 
}
```

Is **not** legal.

However, I am not sure if the first one means, that if case no.1 and case no.2 and so on are different then I can have any number of cases(, of course them being constant expressions) or it means that I can have any number of cases, but *some of them doing the same thing*.

I have found a similar question regarding this: 
 [multiple label value in C switch case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51796397/multiple-label-value-in-c-switch-case)

**Do I interpret it right? If not, what is it I am missing or get wrong?**

Comment: _"You cannot use the same value for two case labels."_ What's actually unclear about that?

Comment: I'm confident that the book in question will give a basic example of what the first one means.

Comment: Two case labels can't be same. See [example](https://ideone.com/apgqGb).

Comment: Yes, the question you linked contains an example of "several case labels for a single case". The wording (case/ case label) is a bit confusing but essetially it's telling you that "you don't have to put executed code after every single `case`, you can group them together if they should do the same thing"

Comment: It's like putting multiple people into 1 room vs putting 1 person into multiple rooms at the same time.

Comment: Can you really use multiple case labels for a single case? Isn't it still one case label per case but some of the cases are simply empty? Saying you can have multiple case labels just adds a special case that isn't needed at all. It's simply falling through all the cases (empty or not) till it hits a break.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is allowed:

```
switch ( expression )
{
    case 1:
    case 2: 
    case 3:
          //some code
          break;
    //...
}
```

And this is **NOT** allowed:

```
switch ( expression )
{
    case 1:
          //some code
          break;
    case 1:
          //some other code
          break;
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 4):

It seems he means the following construction

```
switch ( expression )
{
    case 1: case 2: case 3:
       //some code
       break;
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

> You can use several case labels for a single case.

This just means that for any case you can use as many labels.

For example,

```
switch(choice) {
    // This is valid
    case 1:
    case 2:
        .
        .
    case n:
        printf("\nCase 1 and 2");
        break;
}
```

You might be wondering what's the use of having multiple labels for same case?

Consider an example of asking a user his/her grades of a subject. The user can enter the grades as `A` or `a` for grade A, `B` or `b` for grade B and so on. But you want to handle the cases ignoring whether the user input is capital or small. You can do this:

```
char choice;
printf("Enter your grades : ");
scanf("%d", &choice);

switch(choice) {
    case 'A':
    case 'a':
        printf("Excellent");
        break;

    case 'B':
    case 'b':
        printf("Good");
        break;
        .
        .
    case 'E':
    case 'e':
        printf("You failed");
        break;

    default:
        printf("Invalid grades");
}
```

Comment: `printf("%d", &choice);`?  Did you mean `scanf()`, perhaps?

Answer (score 2):

I think it's a poorly worded way of saying you can have several labels (in reality, case labels or regular ones) on a single statement, or in other words, that you can make use of implicit fall-through.

Example:

```
bool a_or_b_eh(char Ch)
{
    switch(Ch){ //return true; is a single statement so the {} are optional here
        case 'a': case 'b': case 'A': case 'B': return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```